# Display specific categories on a wordpress post loop

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, post, categories

I'm actually using risewp theme (not the pro version). In the homepage I need to show posts from "novita" categories in the "Scopri tutte le novità", and the "escursioni" posts in the "Le prossime escursioni" section.
Actually it seems that both the parts show all the categories.

How can I do that? I already tried the other solutions posted here, but nothing worked. Thanks!

Site:  http://provasiti100.altervista.org/

Answer (score 0):

Get Posts for specific category using function get_posts

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_posts/

and create Short_code for that and use it in the site to display data.

You can also specify dynamic shotcode with attribute like category name;

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_shortcode/

Example:
[featured_post cat_name="novita"]